# How to share my text lIke emoji on Social networking site?

Tags: iphone, social-networking, share

I wont to share my text(string ) on tumbler/twitter/Facebook/other social site(s) site.

i don't know how to share that. can any one have idea or sample code?

Please,help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Break down the problem: what are the different tasks you need to research/learn about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to share the emoji-keyboard then check it here  http://www.easyapns.com/blog and also Social framework there for sharing.

```
-(void)openFBController
{


SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook] == NO) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This device is not able to Share Facebook or Facebook account is not configured." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted....");

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PeekAboo!" message:@"Post Successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
        }};

    [fbController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"@"give ur imagename""]];
    [fbController setInitialText:@"give ur text"];

    [fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"give ur url"]];
    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


//Note:It doesn't show the old albums list to select in fbController in my account,
//I don't know if thats the case with other people as well.
//After I created and transfered the data from FB to device FB.
//All the albums created afterwards were shown in the list.

}


- (void)canTweetStatus {


SLComposeViewController *TweetStatusController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter] == NO) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"This device is not able to Share Twitter or Twitter account is not configured." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}


if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [TweetStatusController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted....");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"PeekAboo!" message:@"Post Successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
        }};

    [TweetStatusController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    [TweetStatusController setInitialText:@"give ur text"];
    [TweetStatusController addURL:@"give ur url"]];
    [TweetStatusController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:TweetStatusController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an API for that and Twitter has an engine. Check out https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine for twitter. And https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk for facebook.

There are also a lot of questions about this on Stackoverflow. I would suggest you look around first before asking.